# Modify JUnit5 @TestTemplate to generate tests in containers

Tags: junit5, junit-jupiter

I've been trying to create a new test library that supports JUnit5 hooks and other features. My test framework dynamically creates tests in an arbitrarily deep hierarchy.

At first I made my own engine extending from the JUnit5 , but then I found that some hooks (like `@BeforeEach`, '@Disabled`, etc weren't supported).

I then tried to use `@TestFactory` only to find out the same hooks aren't supported.

Now I'm using `@TestTemplate` which *does* support the standard JUnit5 lifecycle, but the results are rendered like this:

```
└─ myTestMethod(String) ✔
   ├─ first ✔
   └─ second ✔
   └─ third ✔
```

But I need them to nest hierarchically like this:

```
└─ parentContainer(String) ✔
  └─ childContainer1 ✔
     ├─ testCase1 ✔
     └─ testCase2 ✔

   └─ childContainer2 ✔
     ├─ testCase3 ✔
     └─ testCase4 ✔
```

I can sort of force this to work by using @Nested with multiple @TestTemplates, but this is impractical for my use case as a slight change in parameters could significantly affect how the elements should be nested.

I'm currently making a new annotation that is composed of @TestTemplate and trying to make an extension that might be able to do this, but I think by this point a `TestTemplateTestDescriptor` has already been created and I'm not sure it can be modified.

I see an API for the invocation context, but it isn't clear to me if there is anything I can do to create  Nodes for each of the test cases here. Is there any way to modify the behavior of the `@TestTemplate` to nest the tests differently?

Answer (score 0):

So using some dark magic I found out I could create my own *TestDescriptor* and inject it into the `@TestTemplate`

```
public class MyCustomInvocationInterceptor implements InvocationInterceptor
 

 @Override
  public void interceptTestTemplateMethod(Invocation<Void> invocation, ReflectiveInvocationContext<Method> invocationContext, ExtensionContext extensionContext) throws Throwable {
    if (extensionContext instanceof MethodExtensionContext) {
        MethodExtensionContext methodExtensionContext = (MethodExtensionContext) extensionContext;
         TestDescriptor testTemplateDescriptor = methodExtensionContext.getTestDescriptor();
         // Create my own test descriptor nesting elements properly somehow
         TestDescriptor myNestedDescriptor = makeMyDescriptors();
         // Add it to the standard @TestTemplate descriptor
         testTemplateDescriptor.addChild(myNestedDescriptor);
    }
```

The drawback of this is I needed to put `MyCustomInvocationInterceptor` under the JUnit5 package `org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor` and mix my code with theirs. This was necessary because *MethodExtensionContext* has default visibility.

The JUnit5 team won't support me if this part breaks, but it seems unlikely to be a problem.

However the tests render properly *and* all of the standard hooks and annotations work!